# Help me proving a property of the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove the following property using cofactor expansion along the first row. Not sure if my proof is correct (don't really know what to do with the induction hypothesis), and I got trouble with closing the proof.

**Proposition:** Let $A$ be a ($n \times n)$-matrix, and let $B$ be the matrix that results when we interchange two columns in $A$. Then $\det(B) = - \det(A)$.

**Proof:** We prove this by induction on $n$. For $n = 2$ the theorem can be verified easily. Assume it holds for ($m \times m$)-matrices, with $2 \leq m \leq n$. Suppose we get $B$ by interchanging column $k$ and column $k+1$ in $A$. If $a_{ij}$ are the coefficients of $A$, and $b_{ij}$ are those of $B$, then we have $a_{ij} = b_{ij}$ voor every $j \neq k, k+1$. Furthermore, we have $a_{ik} = b_{i, k+1}$ and $a_{i,k+1} = b_{ik}$. Let $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}$ be two minors. On the basis of the induction hypothesis we have that $\det(B_{ij}) = - \det(A_{ij})$. (can I just conclude this?) We also get: 
\begin{align*} \det(B) &= \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{1+j} b_{1j} \det(B_{1j}) \\ &= \Bigg[ \sum_{j=1, j \neq k, k+1}^n (-1)^{1+j} b_{1j} \det(B_{1j}) \Bigg] + \\ & \Bigg[(-1)^{1+k} b_{1k} \det(B_{1k}) \Bigg] + \Bigg[ (-1)^{1+(k+1)} b_{1, k+1} \det(B_{1, k+1}) \Bigg] \\ &= - \Bigg[ \sum_{j=1, j \neq k, k+1}^n (-1)^{1+j} a_{1j} \det(A_{1j}) \Bigg] + \\ & \Bigg[ (-1)^{1+k} a_{1, k+1} \det(A_{1,k+1}) \Bigg] + \Bigg[ (-1)^{1+(k+1)} a_{1k} \det(A_{1k}) \Bigg] \end{align*}

Now I don't know how to get from this to $-\det(A)$. I think I need one more step, but I don't see what should follow. Any help please?

Comment: What definition of "determinant" are you using ? depending on that, there are much simpler answers, such as using the Leibniz formula, or using the alternating n-linear property of the determinant (which is the basis for its abstract definition).

Comment: A slicker way to do this is to develop the determinant as Imsteffan points out, by defining a [multilinear alternating function](http://algebra.math.ust.hk/determinant/04_theory/lecture1.shtml) of column vectors, showing  that one exists and that the only possibility--with a minor extra condition--is the usual determinant. Then, all the properties follow easily.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't need to prove in this way, use the definition of determinant via permutation, because it will get easy to prove.

Changing two rows $i,j$-th means adding $(ij)$ to each term, this makes odd permutation -> even, even permutation -> odd.

Check page 7: [Determinant definition via permutation](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~anne/WQ2007/mat67-Lm-Determinant.pdf)

Comment: I already proved it that way. I want to prove it now by using Laplace expansion along first row.

Comment: then you do not need to use induction, Write out the terms in the determinant and observe that they can be factored the way you want: for instance if you expand along the first row, you factor $a_{11}$ from all terms which contain it, then  $a_{12}$ and so forth, and now observe that each product with the $a_{1i}$ is the minor determinant you want, The only issue is keeping track of sgn$ \sigma $